# Nginx alias with trailing slashes

Tags: linux, nginx, php, configuration

I have a sub-site working under a parent website like this:

http://example.org/**sub-site** (http://example.org/**sub-site**/ works too)

Everything seemed to work well, including :

./**sub-site**/sub-section

But this url wont work (it returns a 404):

./**sub-site**/**sub-section**/

My current Nginx code is the following :

```
location ^~ /sub-section {

    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/sub-section/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @sub-section;

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }

}

location @sub-section {
    rewrite ^/sub-section/(.*)+$ /sub-section/index.php?$1 last;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your URI pattern is `/sub-site/sub-section` while your location block is `/sub-section`, thus it never processes URIs beginning with `/sub-site`.